# Alternative for android callback function onSizeChanged()

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

Is there any alternative function for the function **onSizeChanged()** in android. It Is being used when the dimensions of the layout are changed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the team, HarmonyOS does not have alternative function for `onSizeChanged()` in android by now. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.